How can I continue the footnote labelling in info boxes in mdframed?
I have several information boxes in a text. My code looks like this:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\mdfdefinestyle{graybox}{
linecolor=gray,
    frametitlefont=\sffamily\bfseries\color{Black},
    frametitlebackgroundcolor=gray,
    frametitle={My Infobox}
    }



\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[
    style=graybox,
    frametitle={Defition: blablabl}]
        \blindtext\footnote{blablabla}
\end{mdframed}

\begin{mdframed}[
    style=graybox,
    frametitle={Defition: blablabla2}]
        \blindtext\footnote{blablabla2}
\end{mdframed}




\end{document}



My output looks like this:

However you can see that the footnotes per box start with alpha again but I want the footnote in box 1 to have alpha the footnote in box 2 betta etc. Do you have a solution to it?
